# Malformed line * in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)

Tags: apt

can someone tell me how to fix this,

```
E: Malformed line 50 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

running Ubuntu 12.04, downloading k9copy when happened,  appreciate your help and please give step by step instructions I am very new to this. Thanks

Comment: The answers to the malformed line91 did not work for me, I did not consider duplicate question because of line number but tried after seeing responses anyway. I'll try the deleting and enable multiverse next.

Comment: Could you add your sources.list content.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? I took Olupot Douglas advice, deleted the source file than update, which solved the problem. Are you wanting to see what was deleted?

Comment: source list to long but can break up in several sections to send if that is what your wanting

Comment: Doesn't matter, you have up to 30000 characters to dump the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and every file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Answer (score 1):

Try making a copy of your sources.list file and then delete the original file (sources.list), and enable multiverse like below[image: taken from k9copy]

then perform an update

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install k9copy
```

Try that and visit [this for details](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/K9Copy)

Comment: I'm going to try this but first would like to know what am I to do with to do with the copy of the source list file?

Comment: keep it just incase you need your original settings. you installed softwares